# PHP EOT Error Message

Tags: php, heredoc

I get a message, when I run this code:

```
function print_footer(){
global $file;
echo <<<EOT
<center>
<a href="$file?op=vote"> Vote </a> |
<a href="$file?op=admin"> Admin </a> | 
<hr>
$copy; 2012, Shibbir Ahmed, All Rights Reserved.
</center>
</body>
</html> 
EOT;        
}
```

**Error Message:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in D:\xampp server\xampp\htdocs\practice
>       \function.php on line ...

What's wrong in this PHP code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have posted here have a bunch of spaces after the ending `EOT;`. That is [not allowed](http://php.net/heredoc) in the PHP syntax:

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier
>   must contain no other characters, except **possibly** a semicolon (;).
>   That means especially that the identifier **may not be indented**, and
>   there may not be any spaces or tabs before **or after** the semicolon.

What happens is that PHP does not see your ending specifier and it therefore continues to look for one, until it unexpectedly reaches the end of the file and throws an error.

The solution is to make sure you have no spaces at all on the line where you have `EOT;`, neither before or after.

Comment: Ok, Fine this is the update <<<EOT and close it EOT;

Comment: Are you sure that you have no spaces, tabs or anything before or after the ending `EOT;`?

Comment: Vikstrom IT'S WORKING...

Comment: Vikstrom it is working for me too. I inserted space for indent.

Answer (score 0):

If the way you formatted your code is anything to go by, it looks like you have whitespace before the `EOT;`. The ending marker of a HEREDOC ***MUST*** be the absolute first thing on a line.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no spaces before `EOT;`

Comment: But there is spaces before EOT, It's just <<<EOT

Comment: no, the other EOT, at the end. That line should only have `EOT;` no spaces whatsoever

Comment: I did it but getting same message..